# Move image(using jQuery) when user scroll the page?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have an image:

```
<img title="<?php echo JText::_('AEROBOT_HELLO'); ?>" src="images/aerobot.png" id="aerobot" align="right" />
```

And I want to move the image (make it visible any time), when user scroll the page. 
I tried this code:

```
            var $scrollingDiv = $("#aerobot");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );          
        });
```

But it's moving the whole content(which is under image) that I have on the page.
So, how to move only the image with the scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the `position:absolute` and adjust the top and left values:

```
img {z-index:1000;top:0; left:0;position:absolute;width: 300px; height: 50px; float:left;}
```

here is the code in example, minimize the browser for the scroll to show up

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EtAaF/)

to make it stay in its parent container, you have to put  *display:block* to both of them, *position:relative* to the parent container. for right alignment put *right:0* to the image;

```
img {
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 50px; 
    background-color:blue;   
    right:0;
    display:block;
}
#parent{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/EtAaF/3/)

Comment: Yes, it's working. One more question. How to align image to the right of the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use JS : use the CSS attribute `position: fixed`. It acts like absolute positionning, but when the user scroll, the image doesn't move up or down.